# Change Ionic button color for a specific button not for all of them

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have this code for multi buttons inside Ngfor and I want just the clicked button to change its color not all of them, how can I do it please?

.html:

```
 <ion-col size="6"  *ngFor="let data of dataArray" >
    <ion-card>
     <ion-card-header>
       <ion-button  class="fav-icon2"  ion-button [color]="ionicNamedColor (click)="changecolor()" >  
        <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
       </ion-button>  
     </ion-card-header>
   </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
```

.ts:

```
public ionicNamedColor: string = 'warning';

changecolor() {
    if(this.ionicNamedColor === 'warning') { 
      this.ionicNamedColor = 'primary'
    } else {
      this.ionicNamedColor = 'warning'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over an **array** through an **ngFor** loop, means many button elements could get created, but **you have only one single** variable for the color attribute, thats why changing for one button, shall change colors for all.

Having said that, you'll have to devise a mechanism so that each rendered button elements through **ngFor** should get its own reference of color variable. Seeing your code, you should either have the color variable inside the **dataArray** array, or maintain a separate array of string equal in length to **dataArray**. Something like this..

```js
public colorArr:string[]= [];

//initially I've populated dataArray with initial colors.
public ngOnInit(){
this.dataArray.forEach(x=>this.colorArr.push('warning'));
}
```

Your HTML would get modified, like this

```js
 <ion-col size="6"  *ngFor="let data of dataArray; let i = index" >
    <ion-card>
     <ion-card-header>
       <ion-button  class="fav-icon2"  ion-button [color]="colorArr[i]" (click)="changecolor(i)" >  
        <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
       </ion-button>  
     </ion-card-header>
   </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
```

And your changeColor mehtod would get modified like this

```js
changecolor(index) {
    if(this.colorArr[index] === 'warning') { 
      this.colorArr[index] = 'primary'
    } else {
      this.colorArr[index] = 'warning'
    }
}
```

So in essence we are maintaing colors in separate array for each single button element, without affecting original **dataArray**.

Another approach could be you create a separate component only for button elements, and pass its relevant data through **@input** decorators. In that case  your this approach of single variable would work.

Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much it works, but with 3 colors I don't know why..not just with primary and warning colors?! & another thing plz.. can it works like this: when someone clicks on it it change it's color and he can't click on it again, smth like making it disabled with the same color that it has changed to?

Comment: I've edited the code, in ngOnInit I was popuplating colors array with 'Warning' text with 'W' (capital w) and checking against lowercase ('warning'). This is why it happened. Should resolve now.

Comment: To disable button, you've got the 'disabled' button property, simply add it <ion-button [disabled]="colorArr[i]!= 'warning'" />

Comment: can I disable it after the first click? I mean the user has the chance to click on it once then it will disable, can I?

Comment: Yes sure, the mechanism shall be the same. You'll maintain an array (of strings) to maintain initial state (lets say 'NotClicked') of all buttons. Upon click you'll modify the state (lets say to 'Clicked') as you did with color change approach. And in the button style, you can put a check against 'disabled' property like [disabled]='clickArr[i]=='NotClicked' this way automatically upon first click, button would get disabld.

Answer (score 1):

here you are using the array named **dataArray** for showing the buttons on the screen.

Add one more property called **clicked** in the object used in the **dataArray**.

So whenever you call the method for changeColor, you just check the property clicked and decide whether to change the color or not.

So your file should be updated with the following code:

```
<ion-col size="6"  *ngFor="let data of dataArray" >
<ion-card>
 <ion-card-header>
   <ion-button  class="fav-icon2"  ion-button [color]="data.isClicked?'warning':'primary" (click)="data.isClicked = !data.isClicked" >  
    <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
   </ion-button>  
 </ion-card-header>
```

Here there is not need to add anything in your typescript file.

Comment: thank you it worked, but one question plz can it works like this: when someone clicks on it it changes it's color but he is not allowed to click on it again .. smth like making it disabled with the same color that it has changed to?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using button index..

```
<ion-col size="6"  *ngFor="let data of dataArray; index as i;" >
    <ion-card>
     <ion-card-header>
       <ion-button 
         class="fav-icon2"
         ion-button [color]="activeIndex==i ? 'warning' : 'primary'
         (click)="setIndex(i)" >  
        <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
       </ion-button>  
     </ion-card-header>
   </ion-card>
  </ion-col>

activeIndex;

setIndex(index) {
  this.activeIndex = index:
}
```

Note: you can change color as per the condition..

Comment: thank you it worked, but one question plz can it works like this: when someone clicks on it it changes it's color but he is not allowed to click on it again .. smth like making it disabled with the same color that it has changed to?